# UINavigation not wotking in my iphone app after chaging root view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, navigationcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing ios application for iphone.
Am facing problem with the login screen..
i have developed app withoughtlogin screen.but now i want to give login option at first and after login i want to show my actual screens of app.

so what i did with code is as follows...

first of all withought login screen the function which i call in appdeleget.m is as follows..

```
-(bool)DeafultSideBar{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ViewController *homeViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
      [navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    SlideTabViewController *rootController = [[SlideTabViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];
    _viewController = rootController;

    LeftSlideViewController    *leftController = [[LeftSlideViewController alloc] init];
    rootController.leftViewController = leftController;
    // [FBLoginView class];

    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;


}
```

this is the function which i m calling from - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method of AppDelegete.`m file

now i want to show login screen so i have made one login Viewcontroller and then i modified my -

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method with this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    LogInViewController *logInViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];


    self.window.rootViewController = logInViewController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;




}
```

and i have one button in login screen and on click of that button am doing same thing which i done before when no login screen in my app as follows.

```
- (IBAction)SignInCalled:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appdelegete=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];

    appdelegete.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ViewController *homeViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
    [navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    SlideTabViewController *rootController = [[SlideTabViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];
    _viewController = rootController;

    LeftSlideViewController    *leftController = [[LeftSlideViewController alloc] init];
    rootController.leftViewController = leftController;



    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    //[self presentModalViewController:rootController animated:YES];
    appdelegete.window.rootViewController = rootController;

    appdelegete.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [appdelegete.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [UIView commitAnimations];



    // [FBLoginView class];




}
```

Now Problem is that everything working but after clicking of that button when the view of application is loaded then not a single navigation process works.i cant navigate to any of other screen with the following code..

```
 ViewController *HomeView=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:HomeView animated:YES];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeView];

        [menuController setRootController:navController animated:YES];
```

i know i have made some silly mistake somewhere in code so can anyone please guide me how to make this problem solve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller hierarchy looks very complicated and not able to figure out what you want to achieve. Below is the updated code changes that I would make first.

First the App delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  LogInViewController *logInViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];

  self.window.rootViewController = logInViewController;
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Then the button ibaction

```
- (IBAction)SignInCalled:(id)sender 
{
  ViewController *homeViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];

  SlideTabViewController *rootController = [[SlideTabViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

  LeftSlideViewController    *leftController = [[LeftSlideViewController alloc] init];
  rootController.leftViewController = leftController;

  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

  self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];

  // [FBLoginView class];
}
```